# Display image from unmanaged memory in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I've got many images from an external source (umnanaged dll) which are to be displayed on a WPF canvas. The external source renders the images and passed back a pointer (IntPtr) to umnanaged memory, as well as size, stride etc.

Currently, I'm loading these images into a WriteableBitmap and then displaying the in the OnRender method of the Canvas. The WriteableBitmap fits this task very nicely.

```
WriteableBitmap temp = new WriteableBitmap(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormat, null);
temp.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, ImageWidth, ImageHeight), pointerToImageData, ImageHeight * stride, (int)stride);
```

Questions:

- Does the WritableBitmap first copy the Image Data to another place (in managed memory)?
- If so, is there any way to directly render the Image Data on screen (e.g. using DirectX?)
- Are there any other tips and tricks which I could use?

Thanks and best whishes

Daniel

Edit: Tried after suggestion by Clemens: using BitmapSource.Create, using this methods heightens the memory consumtion to the point where I start suspecting that the method copies the whole image and Writeable bitmap may not.

Comment: You may perhaps also use the static [BitmapSource.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616046.aspx) method.

Comment: I assume I would again be creating a new managed object sized as big as the image, or? Seems as if that wouldn't really help, but thanks anyway

Comment: You might compare both regarding memory consumption. Maybe there is a difference. I'd assume that WriteablBitmap first creates a large enough buffer for the whole bitmap, and subsequent WritePixel operations write into that buffer. BitmapSource.Create might directly access the buffer you provide.

Comment: Good point, will try it out and post my findings...

Comment: @Clemens Actually, BitmapSource.Create seems to use double as much memory (or at least more than my WritableBitmap solution). I don't know the inner workings of both methods but according to my tests it would seem as if the BitmapSource.Create method is the one which copies all image data...

Comment: Maybe it just creates a WriteableBitmap internally :-) Did you look at the actual type of the BitmapSource returned from Create?

Comment: Not yet, but good point, will try it out, anyway, still trying out options (currently the windows api code pack...)

Answer (score 0):

WPF's Image control displays ImageSource, you need to convert your image to it, and not just `Drawing.Image`. Use [System.Windows.Interop.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.aspx) to convert the image.

I'm not sure how your image is saved in the unmanaged memory, but you can use one of two methods. If it's saved as a bitmap you may be able to use [CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx).

Or you may need to use [CreateBitmapSourceFromMemorySection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefrommemorysection.aspx), here's how: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8d86cd0-10cc-4349-aa9c-e62d7d066508/createbitmapsourcefrommemorysection.

As for the memory allocation, you would always have to copy the image, aside from the fact that you'll have to convert the image to managed memory, the UI thread can't work with anything it didn't create. You must copy the image using the UI thread before you can display it.

Comment: Hi CKill, the converting of the image is not a problem. (Its stored as blob of image data in unmanaged memory, btw). Your last sentence seems interesting, and also seems to confirm my fear that I will need to get fancy for this...

Comment: @Daniel, yes, I've had some work with displaying images in WPF lately. At the end of the day, you'll have to copy the image at least once to the UI thread.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll be able to get the work done by accessing Direct X directly, currently I'm experementing with the http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack which provides a wrapper over DirectX.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you with that, I have no experience with DirectX. But using WPF isn't all that bad. I had to display images from unmanaged memory as well, and got it to display a film at good fps rates.